# My firestore query is not working. Trying to use Timestamp in greaterThan condition but getting an error

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i want to get the documents that have a more recent timestamp than maxUpdated variable which is stored as TimeStamp. if i print it to the console it looks like this:

Timestamp(seconds=1689805896, nanoseconds=163000000)

the dart/flutter code looks like this:

```
final query = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('clubsOverview')
    .where(FieldPath.documentId, whereIn: uniqueNameList)
    .where('updatedAt', isGreaterThan: maxUpdated)
    .get().catchError((onError)=> print(onError));
```

and the error its printing is this one:

> [cloud_firestore/invalid-argument] Client specified an invalid argument. Note that this differs from failed-precondition. invalid-argument indicates arguments that are problematic regardless of the state of the system (e.g., an invalid field name).

how can i fix this?

edit: the error is in this line .where('updatedAt', isGreaterThan: maxUpdated) because if i do it like this the query works:

```
final query = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('clubsOverview')
    .where(FieldPath.documentId, whereIn: uniqueNameList)
    .where('updatedAt', isNotEqualTo: null)
    .get().catchError((onError)=> print(onError));
```

if you need more info regarding the maxUpdated value it comes from a function that i created which gets the value from Isar local database. the value is stored as DateTime, i convert it to timestamp.

```
Timestamp? maxUpdated = await locator.get<IsarService>().getMaxUpdated();


  Future<Timestamp?> getMaxUpdated() async {
    final isar = await db;
    DateTime? updatedAtDateTime =
        await isar.clubOverviews.where().updatedAtProperty().max();
    if (updatedAtDateTime != null) {
      return Timestamp.fromDate(updatedAtDateTime);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that one of your arguments is invalid.  You've already identified that it's probably `maxUpdated`, but we can't see its value.  Please edit the question to show a [complete example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example#complete) that anyone can use to see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.